# Access files from Windows installation in CentOS

Tags: filesystems, centos

I have installed CentOS on my Windows computer.

How can I access my Windows files from CentOS?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Windows partition is NTFS (most probably a reasonable assumption):

First, find out what label your Windows partition has gotten in CentOS. As root, run

```
fdisk -l | grep NTFS
```

The left-most column is the partition label that you need later (assumed to be `/dev/sda1` below - just change accordingly). The right-most column is the file system on the partition, and with `grep` we only pick those partitions that are NTFS.

Then, for CentOS 6, condensed from http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/NTFS:

> For CentOS-6, the EPEL repository is carrying NTFS packages. To install, after enabling the repo per the [Repositories](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories?action=show&redirect=Repositories) page:
>
> ```
> yum install ntfs-3g
> ```
>
> or if you prefer to leave EPEL disabled by default
>
> ```
> yum --enablerepo epel install ntfs-3g
> ```
>
> You may also want to
>
> ```
> yum install ntfsprogs ntfsprogs-gnomevfs
> ```
>
> for additional functionality.
>
> #### Mounting an NTFS filesystem
>
> Suppose your ntfs filesystem is `/dev/sda1` and you are going to mount it on `/mymnt/win`, do the following.
>
> First, create a mount point.
>
> ```
> mkdir /mymnt/win
> ```
>
> Next, edit `/etc/fstab` as follows. To mount read-only:
>
> ```
> /dev/sda1       /mymnt/win   ntfs-3g  ro,umask=0222,defaults 0 0
> ```
>
> To mount read-write:
>
> ```
> /dev/sda1       /mymnt/win   ntfs-3g  rw,umask=0000,defaults 0 0
> ```
>
> You can now mount it by running:
>
> ```
> mount /mymnt/win
> ```